# delete credential from windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

When I log-in to any windows app, two work accounts appear:

[image: example]

I want to delete one of them, but I can't find how.

In *settings > accounts > access work account* there is only one of them (the one I want to keep).

I guess it is possible by deleting some entry in the regestry, but have not found it.

[image: settings]

Comment: The first thing I would try is deleting the user profile for the browser you are using.  This would eliminate a Windows issue.

Comment: I'm not using any browser profiles, thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Which Windows applications are doing this percisely?

Comment: Have you looked in Control Panel, Credential Manager?  That may possibly be helpful to you